# pandas DataFrame/Series value formatting issue

Tags: python, pandas

Let me give an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2), columns=list('ab'))
print(df)

   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

say, I want to select a row with column 'a' == 0, and I know that in my dataframe that there is only one row satisfies this condition.

```
df1 = df.loc[df['a'] == 0]
print(df1)
   a  b
0  0  1
type(df1)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

df2 = df.loc[0]
print(df2)
a    0
b    1
Name: 0, dtype: int32
type(df2)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

As you can see, `df1` is a `DataFrame` instance, but `df2` is a `Series`, although `df1` only has one row.

Now the problem occurs when I try to format the value of `df1`:

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(df1['a']))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-62c2a3e8dbc0> in <module>()
----> 1 print('{:.2f}'.format(df1['a']))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

but it's ok to print the value of `df2`.

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(df2['a']))
0.00
```

I understand that it's because `df1` is a `DataFrame`, `df1['a']` would be a `Series`, but the argument passed to `format()` function expects something other
than a `Series` object. So I tried to walk around this awkwardly:

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(df1['a'].values[0]))
0.00
```

Is there anyway that's more efficient and pythnoic here?

Comment: Are you trying to format all values as strings? Or convert to float?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the data type to `str`, you can use:

```
df = df[df['a'] == 0].astype(str)
```

Result `print(df)`:

```
   a  b
0  0  1
```

Datatypes `print(df.dtypes)`:

```
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

---

If you want to apply a string format, you can use:

```
df = df[df['a'] == 0].applymap('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Result `print(df)`:

```
      a     b
0  0.00  1.00
```

Datatypes `print(df.dtypes)`:

```
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

---

The next solution doesn't change the data.

```
pattern = '{:,.2f}'.format
print df.to_string(formatters={'a': pattern, 'b': pattern})
```

Output:

```
     a    b
0 0.00 1.00
1 2.00 3.00
2 4.00 5.00
```

Comment: thanks. It's just I have several selected one-row dataframe from another dataframe that I want to print out the numerical values with 2 decimals. Not intended to change the dtypes.

Comment: @StayFoolish, I added a third version, which doesn't change the dtypes.